# Applying keypress listener to all subelements

Tags: javascript, keypress, event-listener

Supposing that I have some nested html elements that look something like this:

```
<div class='container'>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>in enough different elements</p>
  <p>that making listeners</p>
  <p>for all of them</p>
  <p>would be a huge pain</p>
<div>
```

Is it possible to write a javascript listener tied to the container div that responds to a keyDown event while any of its child elements are in focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [keydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown) event supports event bubbling, so you can just add the handler to the `container` element like

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.container')[0].addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  console.log('keypressed', this, e);
  //e.target will refer to the actual event target

  log('down in `' + e.target.innerHTML + '` with keycode: ' + (e.keyCode))
})

function log(msg) {
  document.querySelector('#log').innerHTML = msg;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <p tabindex="1">content</p>
  <p tabindex="1">in enough different elements</p>
  <p tabindex="1">that making listeners</p>
  <p tabindex="1">for all of them</p>
  <p tabindex="1">would be a huge pain</p>
</div>
<div id="log"></div>
```